# What is the difference between the instance of parent class and super?

Tags: java

```
 public class Home extends Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application=new Application();
    application.checkAccess();
    super.checkAccess();//error,can not use super in a static context

 }
}
```

I used to think these two(super, application) are the same. But now it seems they are not. What's the difference?

Comment: So you're asking what the difference is between a keyword (`super`) and a variable (`application`)?

Answer (score 0):

super is a call to parent constructor, in your case constructor of Application. you cannot call a constructor from a static method.

Comment: This isn't right; `super()` or `super(<args>)` are calls to the parent constructor, but the `super` keyword by itself doesn't indicate a constructor call. `super` can be thought of referring to the namespace of the parent class.